# Git pull after each merge to a branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I want to automate things such there will be a script that once a merge into the master branch happens, automatically the files on another server will have the updated version.

Like I'm executing git pull to have a copy on the local of the master each time I log on, I want the same process to happen each time a merge into a certain branch happens on a specific server

Can someone share a script that will accomplish this?

Comment: Because of Git's decentralized nature, I think your question begs for more specificity (e.g. "once a merge..." merged where? On someone's local machine?)

Comment: You want to use the git-hooks for that